# Does Frankfurt have two airports?

Tags: germany, airports, frankfurt

I am planning to fly to Frankfurt and I saw that there are two airports: FRA ([Frankfurt Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfurt_Airport)) and HHN ([Frankfurt–Hahn Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfurt%E2%80%93Hahn_Airport)).  Which one is more convenient and closer to cultural places including Mainz and the Rhine Cruise?

Comment: Which is closer can be answered instantly with Google maps, instead of waiting for somebody to find your question here.

Comment: What do you mean by "closer to (...) the Rhine Cruise"? The river Rhine spans much of Germany from North to South, and there are [boat cruises that for much of the way use the river Rhine starting in the Netherlands that go all the way down to Basel](http://www.avalonwaterways.com/river-cruise/romantic-rhine-southbound/waz/). Anywhere in Western Germany is somewhat close to that.

Comment: There are ***not*** two airports in or for Frankfurt.  There's only one, FRA.  You have been misinformed.

Comment: This begs the question of what exactly makes an airport belong to a certain city.

Comment: @JonathanReez The decision of the airport itself. For example, Oxford airport, which has no scheduled commercial flights, recently renamed itself London-Oxford. \*sigh\*

Comment: The other similar one is Düsseldorf-Weeze airport, which is actually further away from Düsseldorf than Dortmund airport - another one used by low cost carriers but which is actually inside the city

Comment: -1 because the question does not exhibit any research effort.

Comment: +1 because it is the result of research effort being stymied,  by misleading facts (that HNN is not actually in Frankfurt), thus asking this question is saving others.

Comment: @DavidRicherby In the US, MHT did the same thing. But it actually does have commercial flights.

Comment: @MichaelHampton MHT's new name probably also makes it less likely for travelers to think it's in England.

Comment: a trivial look at anything really that contain any kind of information on each airport will tell you where they are, and from there it is pretty obvious which is closer.

Comment: @Fattie: the confusion is largely due to Ryanair who have been marketing "Frankfurt Hahn" (HHN) for two decades (they did not fly into FRA for cost reasons until 2016). It was not uncommon for travel agents or passengers to book a connection and think that FRA and HHN are the same place. If you were relying on their route map you might well do the same. Ryanair previously did the same with CRL for Brussels, STN for London, "Milan Bergamo" etc.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: yes, it's a marketing/legal question, not a geographical question as it might seem.

Comment: @smci No, it’s a geography question that is trivially answered by looking at one of the free-to-use mapping websites that are much more widely known than this site. The question is simply about the location of these two airports and has nothing to do with marketing, the law or anything else.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: not it's not., Ryanair's marketing has been intentionally deceptive for decades. In 2000 an Irish expat friend of mine who lived in Japan booked a trip through guess where, and only found that Ryanair's Frankfurt != JAL's Frankfurt, when he arrived in Hahn. I repeat to you that Ryanair described HHN as "Frankfurt" in their materials for years. That's a fact. Whether that is misleading is a legal question about marketing. Not a geographical question. (As I mentioned, Ryanair did the same for Stansted, Charleroi and Bergamo.)

Comment: This one has been running for decades: [German court restores Ryanair's right to use 'Frankfurt-Hahn' name in advertising](https://www.irishtimes.com/business/german-court-restores-ryanair-s-right-to-use-frankfurt-hahn-name-in-advertising-1.1059918) Jun 2002 *"A court in Cologne [previously] forbade Ryanair from using the name "Frankfurt-Hahn" until it clarified in its advertising that the airport was 120 kilometres from Frankfurt. ... The court ruled that, **despite the airport's official name**, the airline was deliberately misleading consumers and breaching German consumer law."*

Comment: @smci No, really. The question is very explicitly about the location of two airports. Read it carefully: it’s only two sentences. You are asking about other things that are not a part of the question on this page.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: no I'm not, the title says "Does F. have two airports?" and the body says "I saw that there are two airports" then asks which one is more convenient, which is a different question. (Stansted is "less convenient" than LHR/LGW, but it's still accepted as a London airport (even though it's in Essex); and can be faster to get to from North London than LHR/LGW). Please do not talk down to me again, you do this often and it's not allowed.

Comment: @smci And Gatwick is in Sussex. But none of this is relevant to the question. I do not dispute that Ryanair describes HHN as “Frankfurt Hahn”. That doesn’t alter the fact that this question is purely about the location of two places and that the location of places is trivially found on maps.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: [Hahn legally describes itself as "Frankfurt Hahn"](https://www.hahn-airport.de/default.aspx?cc=en) and German courts have upheld that (with the caveat that they disclose the distance). The fact that LHR is closer to the center of London than LGW does not mean that LGW is not also a London airport.*"Which one is more convenient"* != *"Is Hahn also in the general Frankfurt area?"*. The former are the words written on the page, not the latter.

Answer (score 50):

[FRA](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Frankfurt+Airport/@50.079989,8.621102,11.25z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x8a74d84d21f8f331!8m2!3d50.0379326!4d8.5621518) is one of the largest international airports in the world, and right next to Frankfurt itself.

[HHN](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/Frankfurt-Hahn+Airport,+55483+Hahn-Flughafen,+Germany/Frankfurt,+Germany/@49.8556697,7.5888305,9z/data=!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x47be180426b4755f:0x3db29c6e96461c58!2m2!1d7.2641958!2d49.9458052!1m5!1m1!1s0x47bd096f477096c5:0x422435029b0c600!2m2!1d8.6821267!2d50.1109221) is a small airport and was completely unknown, until RyanAir started flying there and simply declared it as 'Frankfurt'. It is nowhere near Frankfurt (or near anything).

Comment: Perfectly stated.

Comment: See also [Words most misleadingly named airports](https://www.skyscanner.net/press-releases/world-s-most-misleadingly-named-airports-revealed-skyscanner).  HHN is 4th only to Sandefjord (mislabelled as Oslo Torp), Memmingen (mislabelled as Munich) and Châlons Vatry (mislabelled as Paris) in distance to the city they're named after.

Comment: Fun fact: HHN is closer to Luxembourg City than it is to Frankfurt. Nearest reasonable sized German city is probably Koblenz and that's still 84 km away. In German context HHN is about the perfect definition of "middle of nowhere".

Comment: That "most misleading" article seems to think that people expect airports to be downtown, and that cities don't have some miles of radius anyway.  I wonder what they'd think of my home-town DFW? It's not misleading because it's exactly beteween Dallas and Ft Worth, but it's a 30 to 50 mile drive to get to the farther edges of either metropolitan area.  The parking lot is bigger than the distances listed on the "closest" cities!

Comment: What do you mean by "small airport" because it has some B747 traffic from it.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann , number of passengers for example. HHN has about 2.6 million per year (https://www.hahn-airport.de/default.aspx?menu=traffic_data&cc=en, declining!), and FRA has about 61 million (http://www.fraport.com/content/fraport/en/investor-relations/financial-and-air-traffic-figures/traffic-figures.html)

Comment: So a small commercial airport would be it. I live in an area with a few literal small airports (with a big one) which would make HHN look pretty big.

Comment: @Aganju If you compare an airport with Frankfurt International, *all* other airports in Germany would be 'small' by your definition. In number of passengers, Frankfurt-Hahn is the 11th largest airport in Germany, in freight traffic the 6th largest and it has actually the 4th longest runway to allow heavy freight traffic.

Comment: I am not comparing _an airport_ with Frankfurt international, I am answering the OP's question. Did you read it? The OP did _not_ ask if HHN is an impressive airport with lots of people and freight going through that beats small airports in the US by volume. I recommend you fly through HHN to Frankfurt downtown, and then consider the OP's questions.

Comment: There is also the airport "Vienna" Bratislava, which isn't even in the same country (although fairly close, compared to the other RyanAir destinations).

Answer (score 16):

FRA is about 15 km from the center of Frankfurt.  HHN is about *125 km* away.  FRA is also closer to Mainz than HHN is.

Comment: HHN is a 2h bus ride from Frankfurt Central station with departures every hour during daytime roughly, FRA is 20mins by suburban train that run every few minutes with transport options also at night.

Comment: @JoeBlow according to Wikipedia "The addition of Frankfurt to its name, however, is not an invention of low-cost carriers as is the case with some other airports – Frankfurt-Hahn is the airport's official name as it positioned itself as an alternative to Frankfurt Airport for low-cost and cargo traffic"

Comment: @JoeBlow That comment is wrong in two different ways. First, Ryanair is an Irish company. Second, as Martin points out, the airport calls itself "Frankfurt-Hahn".

Comment: @JoeBlow Ryanair is not a UK company

Comment: This sort of thing is not unique to HHN, or even Europe. For example, [MHT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester%E2%80%93Boston_Regional_Airport) is [92 km](https://goo.gl/maps/wfWmYSvRLZu) away from Boston, but still calls itself "Manchester-Boston Regional Airport".

Comment: @MichaelHampton  Interesting; so would you consider [this list](https://www.skyscanner.net/press-releases/world-s-most-misleadingly-named-airports-revealed-skyscanner) to be inaccurate/incomplete?

Comment: @gerrit I expect all such lists would be inaccurate or incomplete, especially over time. Though I'm sure their "closest airports" list is wrong, as it doesn't list Boston Logan airport, barely two miles from the city center.

Comment: @gerrit another flaw in that list is that it covers distant airports laying a misleading claim to a city that already had one or more closer airports. This is certainly something to be conscious of, but there's another frustrating phenomenon, namely that of cities' primary airports being located far away from their cities. Denver is an example of this.

Comment: The airport did actually change the name from 'Hahn' to 'Frankfurt Hahn' at the same time as Ryanair started flying there. In 2002 Lufthansa processed against Ryanair, claiming the usage of 'Frankfurt' in the airport's name to be deceptive advertising, but lost. It's an oddity, that the airport is not even in Hahn, but partially in Lautzenhausen and Büchenbeuren. Being originally built as a French and then later US military airport, the names were considered too difficult to pronounce and hence 'Hahn' was chosen as the name of a nearby municipality.

Comment: Interesting comment so @JoeBlow's theory was correct then. (BTW "David and Ryan", who is Ryan? Surname Air?)

Answer (score 7):

[Frankfurt Flughafen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfurt_Airport) is the right choice for what you have described.

There is a tube stop in the airport where you can take the "[S-Bahn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhine-Main_S-Bahn)" to [Frankfurt Hauptbahnhof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfurt_(Main)_Hauptbahnhof). It leaves every 15 minutes between 0500 and 2330 and it's a 15 minute ride.

From Frankfurt Hauptbahnhof it's  a 10 minute walk along the river to the [Römer Platz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B6mer) (the cultural center of gravity) where there are riverboats waiting to take you on an excursion up the Rhine river to scenic locales like [Rüdesheim am Rhein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%BCdesheim_am_Rhein) (wine tasting in season).

The same "S-Bahn" leaving from the airport can also take you west to Mainz and [Wiesbaden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiesbaden).